# How do I declare a function and then assign it to a variable in the same line?

Tags: python

I have a `Button` class that has a variable, `when_pressed`, that is meant to be a function. For the sake of the question, let's assume that it will always be a function and not something like an `int`. When your instance of the `Button` class is pressed, the function contained in `when_pressed` gets called. So you could do this:

```
def pressed():
    print("Pressed")
button = new Button()
button.when_pressed = pressed
```

This will print `Pressed` when the button is pressed. Makes sense.

But I won't be needing that function anywhere else. I am dealing with a low-memory environment, so it would be easier to do something like this:

```
button = new Button()
button.when_pressed = function():
    print("Pressed")
```

You could do this in Javascript, so I think it's possible in Python too. But I can't find anything on it. How can I do this?

Comment: Python has something called [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), but they are not really equivalent to Javascript's anonymous function. In Python they can only contain a single expression, i.e variable assignment etc are not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`lambda`](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) function:

```
button.when_pressed = lambda: print('pressed')
```

Here's a good chance for you to learn about them in case you haven't: [lambda functions](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html)

Comment: How would I do this if I need multiple lines?

Comment: To print multiple lines?

Comment: No, when I need to execute multiple statements.

Comment: Well then, you should write a regular function

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda:

```
something = lambda: print("Hello")
```